# How to get SIM, Config, Location, Network Info using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get these types of info as the below images:

[image][image]

and this is from `Testing` one as the below image:
[image]

and those Infos I get it from this code `*#*#4636#*#*`.

So now After researching I found `Dart` and `Flutter` support this device plugins as I found in the below link:

https://pub.dev/packages/android_device_info

and also I found an example that get the device info in the below link:

https://protocoderspoint.com/how-to-get-flutter-device-info-with-example/

Now I need to get SIM, Config, Location, Network Info, using this device plugin API infos..

So how can I solve this one by getting all this Infos as I need also to the way to get the speed of throughput infos...

I hope this question will be clear enough..

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin: [sim_info](https://pub.dev/packages/sim_info)

A Flutter plugin for read SIM information. You can get SIM data for MCC, MNC, country code, etc...

Note: There are similarities and differences between the data available on Android and iOS. Read the usage.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but how about the infos in the picture now I got all device infos except the information in the previous images...
like the mobile measurement infoand mobile location info... I tried to search for that but I didn't find any plugins for this needed requirements :(... I hope you can help me.....